# Disambiguate [zappa] & [zappa-python]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [`zappa`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zappa/info) tag has actually 99 questions, most of all (97 if I count right) about [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/), a Python tool for deploying on *AWS Lambda*.

The tag definition was corresponding to [`zappajs`](https://github.com/zappajs/zappajs) framework, I suggested a [tag edition to update it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22294565), and it was accepted.

Now what about [`python-zappa`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-zappa/info) (created six month ago, 13 questions): Should we set it as an synonym of `zappa` or burninate it?

Comment: Suggested title: Is Dweezil a snake? Sorry, I'll let myself out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zappa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zappa) is a suboptimal name if there are two frameworks with the same name. I suggest keeping [python-zappa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-zappa) and add a new [zappajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zappajs) tag.

I'm not so sure it was a good idea to replace the tag description of [zappa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zappa) before sorting this out here. Especially because you suggested two edits (one for tag wiki and one for the tag excerpt). Only the excerpt was excepted. The wiki is still pending. Now we have a tag where the description points to one thing and the wiki to another one.
In addition, we now have two tags ([zappa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zappa), [python-zappa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-zappa)) for the same library.

Also: When you change the meaning of a tag, you have to make sure that all question that don't conform to the new tag are handled properly.

Next time please ask on meta **before** performing any such action. Especially when you don't have full edit privilege to fix all the things yourself.

Comment: I take good notes of your remark. That was my first time about tag question : I had experience with edit not with meta, that is why I chosen this way.